# Fool a program run from within a shell script into thinking it's reading from a terminal

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

I'd like to write a shell script that does something like the following

```
while read line; do
echo $line 
done<input.txt | ssh > output.txt
```

This is a bit pseudo codey at the moment (the original is at work), but you should be able to tell what it's doing. For simple applications this works a treat, but ssh checks the input to see whether it's stdin is a terminal.

Is there a way to fool ssh into thinking that the contents of my piped loop are a terminal rather than a pipe?

EDIT : Sorry for not adding this originally, this is intended to allow ssh to log in via the shell script (answering the password prompt)

Comment: Calm down, don't assume I'm not aware of this. This is the current method, however to place the key on the server it still need to prompt once for a password.

Comment: Firstly, **you** just edited you question saying you need something to fake keyboard logon. I did **not asume** that. If you're going to subvert that to get your key on some server, there is no secure key anymore. By the way, will update my answer with a slightly more helpful hint.

Comment: If its for ssh - can't you make a script that fits into shh's `SSH_ASKPASS` env var? (ssh(1)).   Just a thought, didn't try it

Comment: (_edited_) AHHHHH - Use public key auth? There are at least ten-billion FAQs on that on the net. Any reason why you can't use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

This problem (after updating your question and various comments, it became clear you are looking for a way to conveniently get public key encryption into place) could perhaps be solved by 'thinking upside down'.

Instead of trying very hard to get your clients public key onto a server that doesn't yet authenticate the client, you can try to receive an authenticated identity (private key) *from that server*.

Simple terms: generate a keypair on the server instead of the client, and then find a way to get the keypair on the client. The server can put the public key in it's authorized_keys in advance, so the client can connect right away.

Chances are that

- the problem of getting the key across is more easily solved (you could even use a 'group' key for access from various clients)
- if a less-secure mechanism is chosen (convenience over security) at least only the security of the client is reduced, not as-much that of the server (directly).

---

Original answer:

Short answer: Nope. (it would be a security hole for ssh, because ssh 'trusts' the tty for password entry, and the tty only)

Long answer, you could try to subvert/creatively use a terminal emulator (look at script/scriptreplay for inspiration).

Why would you want to do it?

Comment: I don't see how this is a security hole, I could for example use a key and then not require a password and pass in my commands one at a time.

Comment: Well, you clearly suggested that _another app_ (**not ssh**) was requiring a tty. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question should have been worded better. Thanks for your answer, I'll be looking into creatively using a terminal emulator as both the target and destination are interchangeable. I do realise how crazy this whole thing must sound to you ;)

Answer (score 3):

`ssh -t -t` will do what you want - this tells ssh to allocate a pseudo terminal no matter whether it is actually running in one.

Comment: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Comment: @sehe: -t is "force pseudo-tty allocation".

Comment: Try it: `echo hello | ssh -t localhost cat`

Comment: @sehe: You try it. `-t` to force allocation, `-t -t` to force allocation even if stdin isn't a terminal.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the tip. However, I'd be surprised if it worked for the OP. I'll remove my -1 in the mean time (subtle little edit of your answer there... <biggrin/>)

Comment: @sehe: It won't affect password entry - but if you do e.g. `echo w | ssh -t -t foobox` it will list you as logged in with a pty. Whether that solves the OPs problem remains to be seen - as he didn't specify what he actually wanted solved.

Comment: He certainly did not mention password entry, @Erik